# looping through the alphabet as String

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

I want to loop through the alphabet with a for loop and add each letter to my `HashMap`

```
for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z';alphabet++) {
    System.out.println(alphabet);
}
```

doesn't work for me, because my `HashMap` is of form

```
 HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Student>> hm;
```

I need my iterator to be a string, but

```
 for(String alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z';alphabet++) {
         System.out.println(alphabet);
 }
```

doesn't work.

Basically, I want to do this:

```
for i from 'A' to 'Z' do
    hm.put(i, null);
od
```

Any ideas?

Comment: us Char instead of String http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047228/auto-increment-alphabet-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically convert the char to a string, like this:

```
for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z';alphabet++) {
    hm.put(""+alphabet, null);
}
```

Although ""+alphabet is not efficient as it boils down to a call to StringBuilder

The equivalent but more effective way can be

```
String.valueOf(alphabet)
```

or

```
Character.toString(alphabet)
```

which are actually the same.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a `char` to a `String`, or to increment a string with `++`. You can iterate on the `char` the way you did in your first sample, and convert that `char` to a `String`, like this:

```
for(char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++) {
    String s = new String(new char[] {letter});
     System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem: When you work with a `HashMap`, you are supposed to map a key to a value. You don't just put something in a hash map. The letter you wanted to put, is it a value? Then what is the key? Is it a key? Then what is the value?

You might think that using "null" as a value is a good idea, but you should ask yourself: in that case, should I use a map at all? Maybe using a `HashSet` is a better idea?

The second problem is that a `HashMap`, like all java collections, only takes objects - both as keys and as values. If you want to use a character as a key, you could define your map as `Map<Character,Map<String,Student>>`, which will auto-box your character (convert it to an object of type `Character`) or you could convert the character to a string using

```
Character.toString(alphabet);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 with Stream API, you can do this.

```
 IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z').mapToObj(var -> String.valueOf((char) var)).forEach(System.out::println);
```