# Printing the letters from A to Z using a Java stream

Tags: java, java-8, char, java-stream

I have this code, but it gives me an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Character

```
Stream.iterate('a', i -> i + 1).limit(26).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Although it is fine to write `int i = 'a';`

I know I can write it like this, but that seems like too much code for a simple task.

```
Stream.iterate('a', i -> (char)(i + 1)).limit(26).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Why is the Java type inference failing?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/32424763/1746118

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The reason why `i -> i + 1` does not compile is because you're attempting to *implicitly* convert an `int` to a `Character` which the compiler cannot do itself alone.

In other words, you can think of `Stream.iterate('a', i -> i + 1)` as:

```
Stream.iterate('a', (Character i) -> {
       int i1 = i + 1;  
       return i1; // not possible 
});
```

As you have noted, *explicitly* casting to `char` solves it:

```
Stream.iterate('a', i -> (char)(i + 1))...
```

Btw this is better done as:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z').forEach(c -> System.out.println((char)c));
```

This is better because:

1. No boxing overhead thus more efficient
2. if you were to stop at say letter `h` with the use of `iterate` you'd have to do more brain processing than just entering `h` as the upper bound with `rangeClosed` because you'd need to find the number to truncate the infinite stream upon.
3. Along with the boxing `iterate` generates an *infinite* stream which in this specific case has more overhead than the *finite* one with `rangeClosed`. Further, it's far easier to run `IntStream.rangeClosed` in parallel, not that you want to in this specific case but it's something to keep in mind. here is some discussion on [Generators as sources](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-java-streams-5-brian-goetz/index.html) by Brian Goetz.

etc...

Comment: "iterate generates an infinite stream which again has more overhead than a finite one." why's that?

Comment: @Alexander Firstly, I will improve my wording as it may not be the best to remove ambiguity. Thanks. I have also included a reference to a blog which might be of interest.

Comment: "an infinite stream which in this specific case has more overhead than the finite one with" that's better :) Good callout on the split performance of this.

Comment: The link is broken. The page seems to have been (re)moved.

Answer (score 18):

How about just:

```
Stream.iterate('a', i -> ++i).limit(26).forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

`i -> i + 1` does not work because `i` is a `Character` and `i + 1` causes an implicit narrowing conversion ([JLS 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)), which is not allowed. You can *explicitly* cast it as was shown. However `++i` works because (From [JLS 15.15.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1)):

> Before the addition, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is performed on the value 1 and the value of the variable. If necessary, the sum is narrowed by a narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.3) and/or subjected to boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to the type of the variable before it is stored.

The `++` operator takes care of the narrowing conversion without us having to explicitly cast it

Comment: Good answer, would have been even better if you explain why `++i` works and  `i + i` doesn't.

Comment: 1  for awesome explanation @GBlodgett